# Why does all nested struct object have the same address when printed out?

Tags: pointers, go

I am trying to find out in `a := b` if `a` will be a different copy of struct like `func pass_by_value(a some_struct)`

But I find that I don't understand the print statement.

Consider this [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TO0BN1lp3E)

```
    nested_level2 := test_assign_nested_level2{}
    nested_level1 := test_assign_nested{nested_level2}
    top_level := test_assign{nested_level1}

    assign := top_level
    fmt.Println("top_level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &top_level)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("1 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &top_level.Level1)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("2 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &top_level.Level1.Level_2)
    fmt.Println("------------------------")

    fmt.Println("assign top_level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &assign)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("1 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &assign.Level1)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("2 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &assign.Level1.Level_2)
```

The output of the above is

```
top_level address
0x10410020 
1 level address
0x10410020 
2 level address
0x10410020 
assign top_level address
0x10410024 
1 level address
0x10410024 
2 level address
0x10410024
```

I expect the output to be similar to

```
    fmt.Println("top_level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &top_level)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("1 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &nested_level1)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println("2 level address")
    fmt.Printf("%p", &nested_level2)
    fmt.Println(" ")
    fmt.Println(" ------------------------------- ")
```

where

```
top_level address
0x421152280 
1 level address
0x421152270 
2 level address
0x421152260
```

each struct have a different address. but it seems like the child struct have the same address as the parent struct.

Why does all the nested element in the struct have the same address?

And does `:=` actually copy a new `struct` recursively? Like the print statement indicated? (ie. `:=` will return a brand new copy of struct with each of its field content also a brand new copy recursively)

Comment: All assignments in Go are copies. The address are the same, because you are taking the address of the same value every time. Experiment with putting some other values in those structs.

Comment: I am trying to print 6 different values, address of `top_level` , address of `top_level. Level1 ` `top_level.Level1.Level_2` etc..... Can you explain why they are all the same?

Comment: Even though assign := top_level, assign will have its own space in memory different from top_level as it is new assignment. Every reference of same location will return same location.

Comment: @user3591466: structs have no size other than what they contain, and you only have a single int value in them. What values do you expect to see?

Comment: @Godfrey it make sense `assign` has a different address than `top_level` since now i know that `:=` will make a new copy of the operand recursively, but it does not make sense to have all the nested struct to have the same address as the parent struct. I must be getting something wrong here.

Comment: @JimB I expected each child struct to have a different address than the parent struct, but it seems like the child struct have the exact same address as the parent address, which confuses me.

Comment: @user3591466: again, structs themselves have no size, they are are only an abstract concept, so there is no reason for them to take up space in memory: https://play.golang.org/p/JOEY_ygSl4

Comment: @user3591466, i agree with JimB here. A copy of a new address will more likely have previous inherited addresses than new everything or else it will be inefficient..

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I am very confused. I print out `nested_level2` `nested_level1` and `top_level` and found that they indeed have different address  [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TIL7TGT_9p) , I also try playing around by adding more element as you suggested and found out that if I add more element, the first field in the struct will always have the same address as its parent [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rA-sx__j7d) . While the second or third parameter will have a different address. I am still confuse on why the behavior is this way.

Comment: @user3591466 "each child struct to have a different address than the parent struct" Go has no notion of "parent" and "child". What you construct has a very well defined memory layout which you try to see by printing addresses. Forget about "parent" and "child" now. It is not helpful. All you code does is giving fancy names to one word in memory.

Comment: @Godfrey I finally understand what you guys meant, I was under the assumption that golang struct work like object in other language where each nested wrap will request a block of memory containing the inner wrap like a russian doll. But it seems like golang struct is optimize such that there is no wrapper and nested concept, any nested struct only implies that the memory address of the actual content is very close to each other, in another word they are all serialize into a block of memory not like a reference pointing to another block of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Types in Go are not autonomes wrappers around other things but just two things: Types allow to attach methods and types provide a layout in memory. For the question here the ability to attach methods to types is irrelevant. Let's take a look a neutral formulation of the question:

```
type A int64
type B { a A }
type C { b B }
```

This declares three types with the following memory layout:

- Type A has the memory layout of a int64 (that is 8 bytes).
- Type B has the memory layout of a single A, that is a int64, so 8 bytes.
- Type C has the memory layout of a single B, that is a single A, that is a int64, so 8 bytes.

Type B in regard to memory layout is *not* a "wrapper" around A, at least the wrapper adds absolutely nothing. From a purely memory-layout perspective defining type B would be useless (but it allows to attach different methods to B than to A).

Now it should be clear that the address of a `c C` is that of the first of its 8 bytes and this is the same as c.b's address which is the same than c.b.a. And any assignment to a C is just a copy of one machine word (on 64bit architectures).

If you define `type D { a A; b B }` it gets more interesting as a D is now 16 bytes long. (Adding more to a D might even leave holes due to padding.) But still does D not provide anything (expect a new method set) to an A and a B adjacent to each other in memory.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are looking for something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Nesting: type T2 struct{ F3 int }
type T2 struct{ F3 int }

// Nesting: type T1 struct{ { F2 struct{ F3 int } }
type T1 struct{ F2 T2 }

// Nesting: type T0 struct{ F1 struct{ F2 struct{ F3 int } } }
type T0 struct{ F1 T1 }

func main() {
    t2 := T2{F3: 42}
    fmt.Printf(
        "%p %p %d\n",
        // 0xc4200120d0 0xc4200120d0 42
        &t2, &t2.F3, t2.F3,
    )

    t1 := T1{F2: t2}
    fmt.Printf(
        "%p %p %p %d\n",
        // 0xc4200120f0 0xc4200120f0 0xc4200120f0 42
        &t1, &t1.F2, &t1.F2.F3, t1.F2.F3,
    )

    t0 := T0{F1: t1}
    fmt.Printf(
        "%p %p %p %p %d\n",
        // 0xc420012100 0xc420012100 0xc420012100 0xc420012100 42
        &t0, &t0.F1, &t0.F1.F2, &t0.F1.F2.F3, t0.F1.F2.F3,
    )
}
```

Output:

```
0xc4200120d0 0xc4200120d0 42
0xc4200120f0 0xc4200120f0 0xc4200120f0 42
0xc420012100 0xc420012100 0xc420012100 0xc420012100 42
```

---

For `T0`

```
type T0 struct{ F1 T1 }

type T1 struct{ F2 T2 }

type T2 struct{ F3 int }
```

is equivalent to

```
type T0 struct {
    F1 struct {
        F2 struct {
            F3 int
        }
    }
}
```

and `T0`, `F1`, `F2`, and `F3` have the same address.

---

In your new example, `T0`

```
type T2 struct{ F3A, F3B int }

type T1 struct{ F2 T2 }

type T0 struct{ F1 T1 }
```

is equivalent to

```
type T0 struct {
    F1 struct {
        F2 struct {
            F3A int
            F3B int
        }
    }
}
```

and `T0`, `F1`, `F2`, and `F3A` have the same address. `F3A` and `F3B` have different addresses.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused on why do they all have the same address? And why does the same address behavior only exist for the first field of the struct like in [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rA-sx__j7d)?